# Does Enterprise DB can be migrated to Cloud SQL from Google Cloud?

Tags: postgresql, import, google-cloud-platform, enterprisedb

I'm currently trying to migrate from a SQL dump file from an EnterpriseDB server to Cloud SQL Product from Google Cloud.

While searching in logs i got these messages:

> "FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "201.xxx.xx.xxx", user "postgres", database "cloudsqladmin", SSL off"

Also:

> "ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "edb_redwood_date""

The file i'm trying to import is a EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL file (version 9.6.6.11) and wanted to migrate to Cloud SQL Postgres (9.6).

As far as i know `pg_hba.conf` is a configuration file in the EnterpriseDB server, what does this file has to do with ? Do I need some normal Postgres file to migrate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: edb_redwood_date is a EDB PAS specific parameter used for Oracle compatibility. This parameter does not exist PostgreSQL community versions. IP of the server which pg_dump you run does not have permission for connecting to PAS server. You should add your IP address to pg_hba.conf and reload PAS server. pg_hba.conf line you adding is like `host cloudssladmin postgres 201.xxx.xx.xxx/32 md5`

Comment: Thanks for your response, is it possible to generate a community version sql dump from EDB? I solved the problem with the IP allowance but still could not migrate even while deleting some uncompatible EDB flags, since it's a big file i don't think this might be the best option.

Comment: Hi Jorge, could you please share the command with all parameters that generates error like edb_redwood_date error?